# Why ropsten has unpredictable block time?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ropsten

I am currently learning ethereum testnets and I read that "Ropsten is the only proof-of-work testnet. It has unpredictable block times and frequent chain reorganizations"
Why ropsten has unpredictable block times and what does it mean with frequent chain reorganizations?

Answer (score 0):

Ropsten has identical parameters than Mainnet.

The problem with block time average is that there aren't monetary incentives so the available hash power is very low.

It happened in the past that a miner testing new equipment caused block generation to be much quicker for a couple of hours, also if many miners go offline block generation will get slower.